# Concatenate multiple columns in a row

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have made a matrix with the code below and stored certain data in it

```
df = []
r = 5000
c = 50
for i in xrange(r):
    r = [''] * c
    table.append(r)
```

So that the matrix looks like this:

```
    0     1          2                 3        4    5     6    7   ...
3   NaN   Nestlé     Africa            Import   
4   NaN   Nutella    Europe            Report   2010 to    2011 
5   Shell            USA               Revenues      2017
```

As every row has an uneven number of columns, I am confused on how to concatenate all columns as one column and ultimately delete unnecessary columns that are empty, so that it would look like this

```
    1
3.  Nestlé Africa Import
4.  Nutella Europe Report 2010 to 2011
5.  Shell USA Revenues 2017
etc.
```

If it is easier to do this in a `pandas.DataFrame` `(e.g. df2 = pd.DataFrame(df) )` then that is also fine by me.

Comment: I'm unsure where your data is coming from, and why it would be uneven? Concatenation is easy enough with the ''.join() method, just let me know where Nestle, Africa, etc. data is coming from and why it'd be uneven

Comment: Hi Abid, data is coming from ocr'd pdf documents with uneven lengths in tables which give those results. However, those results are made up and it just represents my problem

Comment: Why then can you not use the length of the array to determine where to delete your columns?

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas`, you can join the non-empty columns like:

**Code:**

```
df['concat'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(
    [unicode(y) for y in x if not pd.isnull(y)]), axis=1)
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
    0     1          2                 3        4    5     6
3   NaN   Nestlé     Africa            Import   
4   NaN   Nutella    Europe            Report   2010 to    2011 
5   Shell            USA               Revenues      2017"""),
    skiprows=0, header=1, index_col=0)
print(df)

df['concat'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(
    [unicode(y) for y in x if y and not pd.isnull(y)]), axis=1)

print(df['concat'])
```

**Results:**

```
       0        1       2         3     4     5     6
3          Nestlé  Africa    Import                  
4         Nutella  Europe    Report  2010    to  2011
5  Shell              USA  Revenues        2017      

3                      Nestlé Africa Import
4    Nutella Europe Report 2010.0 to 2011.0
5                   Shell USA Revenues 2017
```